# scroll to previous chapter is working but is not doing what i want it to do

Tags: react-native

i am new and been coding for 3 months. i am building a manga reading app with react native and i have a problem with the scroll up to previous chapter. instead of keeping me on the chapter i am scrolling from it takes me to the top of the previous chapter. i have tried scrollToEnd which is close to what i want it to do but it is not there yet. i want it to stay on page 1 of the manga i am scrolling from

```
export default function AsuraViewChapter({ 
route, setHeaderShown, headerShown, 
chapters, currentChapter, setCurrentChapter,
pageContent, setPageContent
 }) {
    const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

    const toggleHeader = () => {
        setHeaderShown(!headerShown);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPageContent();
    }, []);

    const fetchPageContent = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(route.params.chapterUrl);
        const html = await response.text();
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        const images = [];
        $('div.rdminimal img').each((i, el) => {
            const imgSrc = $(el).attr('src');
            images.push(imgSrc);
        });
            setPageContent(prev => [...prev, ...images]);
    };

    const fetchChapterContent = async (chapterUrl) => {
        const response = await fetch(chapterUrl);
        const html = await response.text();
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        const content = [];
        $('div.rdminimal img').each((i, el) => {
            const img = $(el).attr('src');
            content.push(img);
        });
        return content;
    };

    const goToNextChapter = async () => {
        const currentChapterIndex = chapters.findIndex(
            (chapter) => chapter.chapterLink === currentChapter.chapterLink
        );
        if (currentChapterIndex !== -1) {
            if (currentChapterIndex > 0) {
                const nextChapter = chapters[currentChapterIndex - 1];
                const nextChapterContent = await fetchChapterContent(nextChapter.chapterLink);
                setPageContent(prev => [...prev, ...nextChapterContent]);
                setCurrentChapter(nextChapter);
            }
        }
    };

    const goToPrevChapter = async () => {
        const currentChapterIndex = chapters.findIndex(
            (chapter) => chapter.chapterLink === currentChapter.chapterLink
        );
        if (currentChapterIndex !== -1) {
            if (currentChapterIndex < chapters.length - 1) {
                const prevChapter = chapters[currentChapterIndex + 1];
                const prevChapterContent = await fetchChapterContent(prevChapter.chapterLink);
                setPageContent(prev => [...prevChapterContent, ...prev]);
                setCurrentChapter(prevChapter);
                if (scrollViewRef.current) {
                    scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: false });
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const handleScroll = (event) => {
        const { contentOffset, layoutMeasurement, contentSize } = event.nativeEvent;
        const scrollPosition = contentOffset.y + layoutMeasurement.height;
        const maxScroll = contentSize.height;

        if (scrollPosition >= maxScroll) {
            goToNextChapter();
        }
        if (contentOffset.y === 0) {
            goToPrevChapter();
        }
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView
            ref={scrollViewRef}
            style={styles.container}
            pinchGestureEnabled={true}
            maximumZoomScale={10}
            onScroll={handleScroll}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >
            {pageContent.map((page, index) => {
                const pageNumber = index + 1;
                const progress = ((pageNumber / pageContent.length) * 100).toFixed(2);

                return (
                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        <LoadableImage
                            toggleHeader={toggleHeader}
                            index={index}
                            page={page}
                            progress={progress}
                            pageNumber={pageNumber}
                        />
                        {index === pageContent.length - 1 && (
                            <Text style={{ color: '#0b84ff', fontSize: 24, paddingLeft: '30%' }}>
                                Chapter Loaded
                            </Text>
                        )}
                    </React.Fragment>
                )
            })}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const LoadableImage = ({ toggleHeader, index, page, pageNumber, progress }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            {loading ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#545456" /> : null}
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={index} onPress={toggleHeader} >
                    <AutoHeightImage 
                        source={{ uri: page }} 
                        width={windowWidth}
                        onLoadStart={() => setLoading(true)}
                        onLoad={() => setLoading(false)}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ opacity: 0 }}>Page: {pageNumber}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ opacity: 0 }}>Progress: {progress}%</Text>
                    </AutoHeightImage>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </>
    )
}
```